# Why do we need both Hamiltonian and Hilbert Space to specify a Quantum System?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, hamiltonian

From my understanding, when we have the Hamiltonian, in principle we can know the eigenstates for our system of interest. Then, we can calculate everything we want.

In addition, these eigenstates will form a Hilbert space of our quantum system. It seems that having Hamiltonian is enough to specify a quantum System.

However, there are some textbooks which mention we need both Hamiltonian and Hilbert Space to specify a quantum System.

**Why do we really need Hilbert space to specify our quantum system?**

Comment: This seems a bit similar to asking why we need vector spaces if we have Newton's laws...it's essential in developing the theory and making sense of it

Comment: An Hamiltonian in Quantum Mechanics is an operator on some Hilbert space, usually unbounded but self-adjoint. How can you have an Hamiltonian if you don't know where it acts? For example, suppose that $H$ is the operator that stretches every vector by the positive amount $\lambda$. How would you represent $H$ as a matrix? Is it 2x2, 3x3, 147x147?

Comment: As Phoenix87 says, this question doesn't make sense - you cannot give an operator without giving the space it acts on; giving a Hamiltonian without a Hilbert space just doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a mathematical reason and a (sort of) physical reason:

Mathematical reason: The Hamiltonian is an operator on a Hilbert space to begin with.  Without knowing a Hilbert space, it doesn't even make sense to speak of an operator on it.

Physical reason (sort of): What looks like the same Hamiltonian, e.g. the free particle Hamiltonian $H=\frac{P^2}{2m}$, can be meaningfully interpreted in various Hilbert spaces.  For example, the particle could be moving in an unbounded space $\mathbb{R}^n$ or a bounded space like the torus ($\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n$).  This makes an observable difference: The eigenenergies of the Hamiltonian will be different in the two cases (the spectrum is continuous for $\mathbb{R}^n$ and discrete for the torus).

(The reason I say the second issue is "sort of" a physical issue is that the mathematical reason given above actually eliminates this problem: To be rigorous you should always specify first a Hilbert space and then a Hamiltonian, and you will never run into ambiguities like whether the spectrum is discrete or continuous.)

Comment: I am sorry for not specifying my question more. First, I agree that we should have Hilbert space first and it forms the basic mathematical structure of Our Quantum System. What I want to ask is that whether our choice about Hilbert space will affect anything. This is exactly what you mention in your physical reason. However, I don't quite get what you mean by different eigenenergies for different choice of Hilbert space. As long as we have a Hamiltonian, the eigenenergies has already been decided, right? We also have eigenvectors but these vectors will be represented by different state vector.

Comment: Due to different choice of Hilbert space. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you.

Comment: @Wei-TingKuo Perhaps an easier example to illustrate with is the operator $x$.  If the underlying Hilbert space has states that live on $\mathbb{R}$, then $x$ can have any eigenvalue from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$.  If the states live on the unit interval $[0,1]$, then $x$ can only have eigenvalues from 0 to 1.  For the case mentioned above, $H=P^2/2m$, something similar happens.  Over the unbounded domain, $H$ has all positive real numbers as eigenvalues.  Over the bounded domain, the eigenvalues of $H$ are discrete.  The latter case is essentially a square well.

Comment: Okay. So the domain of the Hilbert space will depend on Hamiltonian, right? Like the free particle case. The Hamiltonian of the square well is only physical inside the well (outside the well the Hamiltonian blows up, which is unphysical). Therefore, the Hilbert space domain is bounded. What i want to say here does it have any physical difference if we define different Hilbert spaces for the same same Hamiltonian(it can be bounded or unbounded)? Thank you.

Comment: This question comes from Professor Xiao-Gang Wen's "Quantum Field Theory of Many-body Systems" textbook. In this textbook, he mentions that the difference between gauge and symmetry depends on how we define the Hilbert space. Does it also mean that the only principle for us to adjust our Hilbert space is based on the symmetry in our Hamiltonian?

Comment: @Wei-TingKuo First (and best response): There is no such thing as "different Hilbert spaces for the same Hamiltonian".  This is the proper mathematical perspective.  A Hamiltonian is an operator on a particular Hilbert space, period, and it has no meaning for any other Hilbert space.  (An equivalent way to think about it is that the Hamiltonian generates time translations for a particular Hilbert space, and has no effect on any other Hilbert space. )  See next comment for another response.

Comment: @Wei-TingKuo However, there can be useful ways of identifying Hamiltonians for different Hilbert spaces.  This is the example I gave above.  A more trivial example is the relationship between free particle systems in different dimensions.  $H=P^2/2m$ makes sense in any number of dimensions, 1, 2, 3, ..., but these cases are obviously very different physically.  They even have different symmetries (O(N), for N=dimension of the space).

Comment: @Wei-TingKuo As for what the textbook is referring to, I cannot be sure.  One possible meaning is that, by gauge fixing, we can give an equivalent description of a system with a gauge symmetry.  The gauge-fixed system may be representable by a different Hilbert space (or else a surface within a Hilbert space).  The gauge-fixed system & Hilbert space no longer has the original gauge symmetry.  Strictly speaking, it also has a different Hamiltonian (in the sense mentioned above), though its Hamiltonian obviously has the same physical content as that of the original system (w/out gauge fixing)

Comment: Agree! So convincing. Your answer is great. Thanks for your patience and clear explanation. I got it.

Comment: @Wei-TingKuo Also, in your above comment, you are thinking of a square well as being defined on the Hilbert space of functions over the entire real line, with a potential defined also on the entire real line, which has infinite magnitude outside of a finite range.  An alternative (more mathematically sound) way to view the square well is as being defined on a totally different Hilbert space: Periodic functions, or functions of an interval.  Then the potential on this space is uniformly zero, and the Hamiltonian is exactly the "free particle Hamiltonian", just on a different Hilbert space.

Comment: @Wei-TingKuo Also, you may find the Wikipedia article on "Particle in a Ring" enlightening.

Answer (score 1):

Both the Hilbert space and the Hamiltonian are needed, but there exists a duality between the Hilbert space and the Hamiltonian. The more general you make the description of the system and thus the larger the Hilbert space becomes, the simpler the Hamiltonian becomes.

Consider e.g. the Hamiltonian describing a simple molecule live H2O. This is an extremely complex Hamiltonian, it contains all the interactions between all the electrons in this molecule. However, this Hamiltonian only applies to states where there right number of electrons and nuclei are present. Suppose we  consider a larger Hilbert space and a more general Hamiltonian. E.g. the Hamiltonian of the Standard Model can describe systems that need a larger Hilbert space to be specified. That Hamiltonian is far simpler to specify than the Hamiltonian of an H2O molecule, but you now need more information to specify a state of H2O in the larger Hilbert space that the Standard Model describes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What i get confused about your explanation is that the meaning of "more general". Do you mean that we have less degree of freedoms in more general Hamiltonian? Thank you

Comment: @Wei-TingKuo Yes, this is assuming you are dealing with the known laws of physics, not some artificial model. The fundamental laws are simple to state, buy when you consider some given system the degrees of freedom of which are mostly "frozen" except for a few, then the few remaining degrees of freedom will be described by an effective Hamiltonian, which can be extremely complex.